# Method within a method java

Tags: java, overriding

I am reading some java code and I came across the following unfamiliar syntax:

```
controler.addOverridingModule( new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        public void install() {
            this.addPlanStrategyBinding("RandomTripToCarsharingStrategy").to( RandomTripToCarsharingStrategy.class ) ;
            this.addPlanStrategyBinding("CarsharingSubtourModeChoiceStrategy").to( CarsharingSubtourModeChoiceStrategy.class ) ;
        }
    });
```

I am confused because the developer created a new method ("install") within the call to addOverridingModule. Could someone please tell me what is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: the method install is a method of the inner class `AbstractModule`.

Comment: The entire expression consisting of `new AbstractModule { /* ... */ }` is an *anonymous class instantiation*. Off to find a dupe target...

Answer (score 0):

`addOverridingModule` expects an instance of type `AbstractModule` (which can be a class or an interface - it's not clear which of the two is it in your example, but it doesn't matter).

This snippet is passing to it an instance of an anonymous class that implements/extends `AbstractModule`. `install` is a method required by `AbstractModule`.